# SDK 2.0 - Schema takes exceptionally long time to load

Tags: sdk, rally

I have been working to convert some of my previous apps to the new 2.0 SDK and have been running into some problems during initialization. I see that the SDK is now loading a schema for the various data models when the page loads, and while this file is relatively small in size (57.3KB) it's taking an incredibly long time to load, usually around 45 seconds.

Is this a known issue? And if so, are there any methods to avoiding it?

[image]

Comment: Hi Conner, are you running your apps externally, or within Rally? I'm surprised it's taking that long, that is something we are looking into. Currently external apps are forced to download the schema each time, which is something we are also working on fixing.

Comment: For the example screen shot shown above, I just loaded the endpoint directly in the browser, using the URI I pulled out of one of my apps when it was first loading. The weird part is, sometimes this file loads very quickly, and other times it takes this long to load. I actually participated in the RallyON Hackathon and we were experiencing this error there as well and actually ended up switching back to p5 just for this reason. I would like to continue to use RC1, but this makes most of my apps unusable.

Answer (score 1):

Great news!  As of 11/13 this issue should be resolved!  We were finally able to analyze the underlying performance issues and push a fix for this problem.

Comment: pinging @ConnerReeves so he sees the news